# Choose an app on "open with"

Tags: windows-10s

On Windows, when I try and open a file that doesn't have a program registered for its extension, it asks you "How do you want to open this file?" and shows you a list of suggested programs it thinks will be able to open the file.

[image]

Clicking "More apps" shows a list of apps, and at the bottom you have the option to "Look for another app on this PC".

Clicking on that opens up a "file-finder" in program files. Which is fine if you want to open a win32 application.

But if you want to open the file with a UWP app? How can you do that?

[Cannot set a Windows 10 Store App as default program to open a file](https://superuser.com/questions/1071323/cannot-set-a-windows-10-store-app-as-default-program-to-open-a-file) gives you a way to add these via regedit.

However, Microsoft has recently announced Windows 10 S, which only allows apps from the Store, and **regedit is blocked/banned**. So is there a graphical way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible dupe of [Cannot set a Windows 10 Store App as default program to open a file](//superuser.com/q/1071323)

Comment: Click "Look for an app in the store", installed applicable UWP applications, already appear in the list